# Declare const with variable values

Tags: delphi, custom-data-type

in other `PL` we can declare `const` `Test = 'my test '+inc(someVar)+' is work';`
how to simulate this in delphi?
my delphi example may be like that:

```
const
  Msg = 'some todo-Tasks will Start in [ '+Timer1.Tag.ToString+' ] Seconds.';
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to achieve.  One option might be to declare a constant formatting string like this: ``const msg = 'some todo-Tasks will start in %d seconds.';`` then in your code you use ``Format(Msg,[Time1.Tag]);`` to return the string with the seconds filled in.

Answer (score 3):

In modern versions of Delphi, this can be achieved by means of inline variable (and constant) declarations:

```pascal
begin
  // code
  const Msg = 'Some text ' + (a + b).ToString + '.';
  // more code...
```

Classical (non-inline) Delphi constant declarations cannot contain non-constant expressions; they are evaluated at compile time. An inline constant declaration like the one above, on the other hand, is executed at runtime as a statement. The RHS can be any valid expression. You can think of this as declaring a read-only variable with local scope and the statement being an ordinary variable assignment.

Comment: thanks @Andreas Rejbrand (so outside local scope is not implemented yet ?)

Comment: @MBen: If you mean non-inline variable declarations, that's even mathematically impossible and so it cannot ever be implemented. Code that is outside functions and procedures (and programs, initialization sections and finalization sections) is not executed at runtime, but only at compile time (if at all). So runtime expressions cannot possibly be present in such places! [Well, you could argue that such an expression could be reevaluated each time it is found in a runtime expression, like a simple substitution. But then we run into a lot of subtleties regarding scope etc. Besides, that would...

Comment: ...essentially be a function!]

Comment: @andreas that's not true. Other programming languages allow you to initialise constants with runtime evaluated expressions. An example might be data members of class instances.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I suspect we are not thinking about the same thing. Suppose you have `implementation const UserName = InputBox('Enter your name'); procedure Greet; begin ShowMessageFmt('Welcome, %s!', [UserName]); end; ...`. When exactly would the input box be shown? Every time you invoke `Greet`? At the first invocation of `Greet`? At unit initialization?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: But I agree the wording in my comment was ambiguous. I don't mean a programming language cannot reasonably have a feature that is reasonably described as "global constants initialized by run-time expressions"; I simply meant that Delphi true constants, as of today, are rather fundamentally incompatible with run-time evaluation and that it wouldn't be a simple task for Embarcadero to add such support (nor would it be obvious how that would even work and behave).

Comment: @andreas the question asked was about scores that aren't local. There are many scores that aren't local that also aren't global or program wide.